# Generate a list of AWS products available in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to generate a list programmatically of all aws [resource types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) available in CloudFormation?

A resource type being ec2, s3...

Regards
Conteh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [list-types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-types.html):

```
aws cloudformation list-types --visibility PUBLIC --type RESOURCE
```

Since there is a lot of resources, you will probably need to execute the command multiple times to account for pagination.

Answer (score 4):

[CloudFormation Resource Specifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-resource-specification.html) can be parsed using something like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```sh
curl -s --compressed https://d1uauaxba7bl26.cloudfront.net/latest/gzip/CloudFormationResourceSpecification.json | jq '.ResourceTypes | keys'
```